# what is the difference between 100 W and 1000 W step down transformer?

Tags: transformer, watts, step-down

I need a transformer of 1350 W and just realize that it is very expensive compared with one of 30 W.

What is the physical difference of transformers from 220 to 110 V of 100 W and other of 1000 W?
Or what determines the watt capacity of the transformer?

(Why transformers of 1000+ W are so expensive??)

for example, i have a hand dryer of 110 V, 1350 W and I have wall power of 220 V.

power = I * V
I = 1350/110 = 12,27 amps
so the wire of the second winding needs to hold 12.27 amps, an AWG 10 wire should work, right?
Maybe AWG 9 for more safety.

Is the wire amp capacities the only requirement for the transformer to work properly and without setting on fire?
I have read something about the size of the core, but didn't find exactly how it influences the specifications of the transformer.

Is the same a transformer 220 V to 110 V of 2 turns-1 turn, or 200 turns to 100 turns or whatever whit the 2:1 ratio turns?

I would like to try a DIY transformer if it were within my reach. (I have the core of a cheap and small 220 - 12 V transformer, and also I could get the one from a microwave), and even if I can't (safety first), I'm still curious about what I have asked.

Comment: *"what is the physical difference of transformers from 220 to 110v of 100w and other of 1000w?"* The mass of iron used and the diameter and mass of the copper windings, for the most part. More iron and more copper means more money.

Comment: I was going to say "lots of smoke".

Comment: Go to any builders merchant or serious tool store. 110V is commonly used on building sites so they will stock rugged 2000W-3000W step down transformers, usually in tough bright yellow cases, and remarkably cheap.

Comment: It's just bigger. Be safe if you try to DIY one!

Answer (score 1):

Sell the 110v devices like the hairdryer and get ones designed to run at 230v.

Are you planning 1 transformer for each device - you will get bored of moving it.

I do have a 230 to 110 transformer for the professional router I possess.

Comment: I take it that's the woodworking kind of router and not the computer kind

Answer (score 1):

A 1000W transformer is bigger than a 100W one.  Transformers are not 100% efficient, and get warm in use.  A transformer run at its maximum power for a long time can get quite hot.  One run at ten times its rated power will get very hot indeed.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the difference between 100 W and 1000 W step down transformer?

About 900 VA ;), and cost per VA depends on quality and quantity, often $0.1 / VA.

They use VA as a measure rather than W because you must derate VA to W if using low power factor like a DC bridge & large cap.

Answer (score 0):

The quantity of silicon steel and copper that would be required to manufacture a transformer would be dependent on its wattage. In other words, wattage would decide the price.

It does not follow that, to reduce the price, wattage could be reduced.

The only possibility would be to reduce the requirement of silicon steel and copper.

The costly option would be to use an isolation transformer.

[image]

The cheaper alternative would be an auto-transformer that could be had at around 50% of the cost of an isolation transformer.

[image]

It is apparent that the auto-transformer would not provide isolation.